Quill inline images
does anyone have experience adjusting the CSS of Quill so that it will allow more than one inline image, even small images. We find that with all the formatting tools in place, quill only allows one image in a line and if another image is placed, quill jumps and makes a new paragraph to embed the image.
tried to change the CSS code but was unsuccessful
